# How to return player name and position when user searches SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

So I'm wondering how I can create a procedure to return the players name and the players position when a user is prompted to input a player name.  So if they put in 'Sam' it will return any player with the text 'sam' in their name e.g Samora, Samantha, Sam.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc_search
  (name IN player.playername%TYPE)

AS
BEGIN

SELECT playername, position
FROM player
WHERE playername LIKE %name%;

END PROC_SEARCH;
/

SET SERVER OUTPUT ON

SET VERIFY OFF

ACCEPT input_playername PROMPT 'Please search for player';

DECLARE
playername player.playername%TYPE := '&input_playername';

BEGIN
      proc_search(playername);


END;
  /
```

Is this close?

Comment: What client (Java/C# etc.) is the user on? PL/SQL procedures shouldn't handle/poll user input.

Comment: I am using oracle sql developer and creating procedures in PL/SQL to query the databsase.

Comment: What I mean is that if there is a "player" table in the DB, I'd expect that there is also the "game" that's being played. It should be the game's responsibility to get the input from the player/user, not the RDBMS's.

Comment: No, I just have a table called player that I created which has name, position, age.  Now I want to create a procedure to output the players with similar name to the input.  Its just to practice writing procedures.

Answer (score 1):

The procedure that outputs players' names to `dbms_output` could look like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE proc_search (name IN player.playername%type) IS
  CURSOR get_players IS
    SELECT playername,
    position
    FROM player
    WHERE UPPER(playername) LIKE UPPER('%' || name || '%') ORDER BY playername;
BEGIN
  FOR plr IN get_players LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line(plr.playername || ' is at ' || plr.position);
  END LOOP;
END;
```

This will find all players whose name contains the given input string (case-insensitive). You can execute the procedure from an anonymous PL/SQL block in SQLDeveloper (remember to activate the "Dbms Output" view first):

```
BEGIN
  proc_search('sam');
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

A flexible way to do this is to have your procedure (or more properly, a function) return a cursor which the code that called the function can then iterate through:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func_search(name IN player.playername%TYPE)
  RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
AS
  csrReturn  SYS_REFCURSOR
BEGIN
  OPEN csrReturn FOR SELECT playername, position
                       FROM player
                       WHERE UPPER(playername) LIKE '%' || UPPER(NAME) || '%';
  RETURN csrReturn;
END func_search;
```

When invoking this function from PL/SQL you'd do something like:

```
DECLARE
  csr  SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  csr := func_search('sam');

  FOR aRow IN csr LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('PLAYERNAME=''' || aRow.playername || '''' ||
                         '  POSITION=''' || aRow.position || '''');
  END LOOP;
END;
```

You can also invoke `func_search` from code written in some other language which might then allow a web page, as an example, a way to display player names and positions.