# Open a refcursor for a PL/SQL statement?

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor, sys-refcursor

I'm creating a report for a business using Oracle and SSRS. The report requires me to aggregate contiguous ranges of serial numbers, which can consist of alphanumerics.

For example, say I have the following serials:

```
OPS114
OPS115
OPS116
OPS117
OPS145
OPS146
OPS160
890RPT
896RPT
897RPT
```

The report should have a single aggregate row for each contiguous range, with the count of each range, like so:

```
OPS114 - OPS117 (4)
OPS145 - OPS146 (2)
OPS160 - OPS160 (1)
890RPT - 890RPT (1)
896RPT - 897RPT (2)
```

I've pulled the data I need, and I'm bulk-collecting it into a table variable. Now, I need to aggregate the rows - this wouldn't be bad if I only needed to manipulate the data, but I need to have this available as a query for the refcursor. Can I open a refcursor for a PL/SQL FOR loop, or am I barking up the wrong tree? I've attempted to Google this, but the "cursor for loop" is not what I'm looking for. The alternative is to try to aggregate the results in SSRS using VB. (So either way, it won't be a good time.) I'm not sure if I have access to create a SQL table type for this, so this is the alternative I've sought.

If anyone has any experience with this, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Aggregate data using pivot or stragg or listagg and then open a ref_cursor to return the results.  Where did you need more assistance?

Comment: @kevinsky Pivot won't work for my needs. Your comment just helped me learn about STRAGG and LISTAGG - the latter seems closer to what I might need, but I'm not sure if I can get the results I want (or the display that I need). Yes, those built-in functions do return a resultset, but unless I can pass a custom sorting function to them, I doubt they'll work for what I need. Where I need more assistance - I want to have a custom PL/SQL function write results to a refcursor. Is this possible?

Comment: Sure, you can use a custom user created function or a built in.  In order to answer your question can you provide the table structure and any other relevant detail?

Comment: One simple example of returning a `SYS_REFCURSOR` from a function is in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29453345/905488).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this from a single SQL statement but you need to define the data better. Your column stores strings but you are using them as numbers to find out the range. And it seems the number part could either be before or after the string part.

If you are able to write some logic that separates out the numbers like this (and maybe keep the string part in another column)-

```
114
115
116
117
145
146
160
890
896
897
```

Then it reduces to a simple [gaps and islands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gaps-and-islands) problem.

Step 1 - Select rownum along with this column (this would be a continuous sequence starting from 1)

Step 2 - Subtract rownum from this numeric data column.

Step 3 - Group by that result

Step 4 - Get min(numeric value) and max(numeric value) and count(numeric value) from the group which will be your result when combined as string.

```
Numeric_part     Rownum      Difference
------------     ------      ------------
114              1           113
115              2           113
116              3           113
117              4           113
145              5           140
146              6           140
160              7           153
890              8           882
896              9           887
897              10          887
```

Grouping this by Difference column, you get -

```
Difference     Min(num)    Max(num)    count(num)   Result
----------     ---------   ----------  ----------   -----------------
113            114         117         4            114 - 117 (4)
140            145         146         2            145 - 146 (2)
153            160         160         1            160 - 160 (1)
882            890         890         1            890 - 890 (1)
887            896         897         2            896 - 897 (2)
```

That SQL statement can be used in PLSQL to return a cursor as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29451603/how-to-return-player-name-and-position-when-user-searches-sql/29453345#29453345) link that @MickMnemonic has in the comments.

Basically -

```
OPEN cursor_variable FOR SELECT something FROM something...;
```

Comment: Although I found a solution to this problem, depending on the way we have to sort data, I think this is a better answer. Changing the table definition is definitely logical if we don't have to sort on character data as well, and would make things a lot easier and faster (I'm using a regexp call to separate the data on every loop iteration). That said, we do seem to have records like "AB123C", "B456CD", etc....so we may actually have to sort on the character data. If this is the case, determining ranges might be more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

I spoke to a coworker about this and he had an idea that I've been able to implement.

I was able to create a pipelined function that handled my data selection and transforms for me; this allowed me to aggregate my rows as I needed to and only pass rows after a contiguous range was complete.

I am now calling that function from a procedure using the `SELECT ... FROM TABLE(MYFUNCTION())` syntax. This allows me to get everything into a refcursor without much issue.

While this may not be performant (looping over a cursor, and manually aggregating), this is for a monthly report, and so I won't attempt to optimize until it's necessary (as we have other work to do).